# Taking identical balls from distinct boxes

Tags: combinatorics

Consider $l$ distinct boxes. In the $i$th box there are $a_i$ balls. All the balls in these boxes are identical. If I want to take $s$ balls in total from these boxes, how many ways $n(a_1,a_2,...,a_l,s)$ are there?

In the case $s=1$, we have $n(a_1,a_2,...,a_l,1)=\sum_i\text{sign }a_i$.

Comment: You want the number of solutions of the equation $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_l = s$ in the nonnegative integers subject to the constraints $x_i \leq a_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq l$.